# how to change background img size

Tags: jquery, css

```
   $(this).css('background','url(img/49057_584817416_4750_q.jpg) no-repeat 10% 40%,url(img/yes_no.png) no-repeat 50% 80%,url(../img/invitation.png)');
```

I only want to resize img/49057_584817416_4750_q.jpg

Any Thought?
Thank you.

Comment: This topic will give you solution to ur problem.
[ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143517/jquery-resizing-image]

Answer (score 0):

you can refer the below link for more information

http://johnpatrickgiven.com/jquery/background-resize/

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking if you can resize one background image on an element without resizing the others using just css? The answer to that question is no. If a property has one value it counts for all background images.

If you're using js to create this you're most likely better off injecting the images, positioning them absolutely to take them out of the flow, and sizing them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Through CSS3, you can do something like this

```
-webkit-background-size: 80% 80%; /* Saf3-4 */
     -moz-background-size: 80% 80%; /* FF3.6 */
          background-size: 80% 80%; /* Opera, IE9, Saf5, Chrome, FF4 */
```