# why does my LAMP stack show my image when I navigate to it w/ a URL but not when I load it w/jQuery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, lamp

I have a php file at `path/renderer/renderImage.php` that builds and returns a PNG image to the browser. When I navigate to that URL with my browser, it dumps the correct image on the screen. But when I try to load that image into a DIV with jQuery using the code below from path/index.html ...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8'/>
        ....
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="../jquery.colorbox.js"></script>
        <script>
            $.colorbox({
                width:"30%", 
                inline:true, 
                href:"#inline_content",
                onClosed: function() {
                    $("#myPic").load('./renderer/renderPicture.php');
                    $('#myPic').css('display','inline');
                }
            });
```

it fills the DIV with strange symbols...

[image]

Here is a picture of the directory structure:

[image]

Why is the browser interpreting the picture differently on these two pages? What might cause the discrepancy?

Comment: rather than .load, try .html instead. .load is shorthand for an ajax request.

Comment: @stefancarlton, how will having a path to a file as html content help?

Comment: ack, thanks @mishik. Plonker moment by me! You'd need to create a img element and put the SRC there instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting symbols instead of an image since you are trying to send binary data without specifying what that data is.

Add **header** to your **renderPicture.php** file :

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

And it will return the desired png image.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The jQuery [.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method will load TEXT/HTML content and insert it into the document. This is exactly what happens in your case, and is expected behavior.

To load an image via jQuery you can use:

```
$('<img src="./renderer/renderPicture.php">')
```

and then make use of the .load (event) to do something:

```
$('<img src="./renderer/renderPicture.php">').load(function() {
    $(this).appendTo('#myPic');
});
```

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863680/2327283