# function is too fast?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function actually works, but I don't think it's a good solution. If I do not add setTimeout, the function does not work well. (It only loads maybe half of the pictures).
Is there a problem that I do not use "i" within the for-loop?

And is it a "good" solution to load the `<img>` tags into a hidden "load" div to work with them and sort them into 3 different divs?

```
function loadpictures() {
  $('#load').empty();
  $('#picTop').empty();
  $('#picMiddle').empty();
  $('#picBottom').empty();

  $('#load').load('pages/bilder.html .' + category, function() {

    LineW[0] = LineW[1] = LineW[2] = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < $('#load img').length; i++) {
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        var shortLine = 0;
        for (var j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
          if (LineW[j] < LineW[shortLine]) {
            shortLine = j;
          }
        }
        switch (shortLine) {
          case 0:
            $('#picTop').prepend($('#load img')[0]);
            LineW[0] += $('#picTop img')[0].offsetWidth;
            break;
          case 1:
            $('#picMiddle').prepend($('#load img')[0]);
            LineW[1] += $('#picMiddle img')[0].offsetWidth;
            break;
          case 2:
            $('#picBottom').prepend($('#load img')[0]);
            LineW[2] += $('#picBottom img')[0].offsetWidth;
        break;
    }
  }, 20);
}
```

});
}

Comment: but what the function is supposed to do?

Comment: the function loads img tags with have class X from another file into a hidden div "#load'

And then i sort the pictures into 3 visible DIVS depending on the overall width of each div (always add the next picture to the shortest)

Comment: If you have a solution you should post that as an answer and accept it. It's OK to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced the for-loop with the .each jquery function now it works perfect for me :) Thy anyways!

```
$('#load').load('pages/bilder.html .'+category, function(){

$('#load img').each(function () {
    var shortLine = 0;
    for(var j = 1; j < 3; j++){
        if(LineW[j] < LineW[shortLine]){
            shortLine = j;
        }
    }
    switch (shortLine) {
        case 0:
            $('#picTop').prepend($('#load img')[0]);
            LineW[0] += $('#picTop img')[0].offsetWidth +5;
            break;
        case 1:
            $('#picMiddle').prepend($('#load img')[0]);
            LineW[1] += $('#picMiddle img')[0].offsetWidth +5;
            break;
        case 2:
            $('#picBottom').prepend($('#load img')[0]);
            LineW[2] += $('#picBottom img')[0].offsetWidth +5;
            break;
    }
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[This example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863658/load-image-with-jquery-and-append-it-to-the-dom) waits for images to load. If you want to refactor it, I would suggest getting an array of image paths then using his/her function.

```
function loadImage(path, width, height, target) {
  $('<img src="'+ path +'">').load(function() {
    $(this).width(width).height(height).appendTo(target);
  });
}
```