# jquery how to alert after preloading image

Tags: jquery, image, preload

hi i'd like to preload an image using jquery.
After the image is preloaded there should be an alert message: "image preloaded"

i tried the following code but it doesn't work:

```
$("images/test.jpg").load(function(){
  alert("Image loaded.");
});
```

hope u can help.

Comment: `$("images/test.jpg")` ??? That's not how it works, please start from the beginning, reading some tutos

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this plugin for JQuery: http://plugins.jquery.com/imagesloaded/

You can fire off an event just as you propose as long as your selector is scoped correctly:

```
$('#container').imagesLoaded( function() {
  // images have loaded
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need an id which will contain that image.

```
$( "#div" ).load( "images/test.jpeg", function() {
alert( "Load was performed." );
});
```

See the documentation at http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I guess OP was looking for onload event of an image

Comment: @A.Wolff it is not evident what he really wants to achieve... Load an image in an element or just load an image.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you want:

```
$("img[src='images/test.jpg']").load(function(){
  alert("Image loaded.");
});
```

Now what about reading the DOC: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/  ???

That's said, be aware of cache behaviour, especially on older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

the following solution worked out for me:

```
$('<img src="images/test.jpg">').load(function() {
      alert("Image loaded.");
});
```

i found it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10863680/1164027