# Resize image for fixed height and fixed width with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, image-resizing

There are resizing answers at [Jquery resizing image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143517/jquery-resizing-image)

In the code, there is:

```
var maxWidth = 100; // Max width for the image
var maxHeight = 100; // Max height for the image
```

Is it possible to resize to fixed size of 100px x 100px?

Comment: This can be done with CSS `width:100px;height:100px;` however, the image will be stretched and look funny this way.  you might be interseted in the jcrop library

Comment: I am using the user uploaded images inside a step carousel. jcrop library doesn't work there.

Comment: CSS has the **clip** property that can be set on absolutely positioned elements. [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/kajid/3/edit).

Answer (score 1):

Or you can use CSS as `background-image` while `background-size: cover; background-position: center center;`

Comment: It needs to be img tags