# resize an image after it is rendered using angular/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

My html look like this,

```
<img width="150" height="150" src="https://d.pcd/image/578434201?hei=75&amp;wid=75&amp;qlt=50,0&amp;op_sharpen=1&amp;op_usm=0.9,0.5,0,0" ng-src="https://d.pcd/image/578434201?hei=75&amp;wid=75&amp;qlt=50,0&amp;op_sharpen=1&amp;op_usm=0.9,0.5,0,0">
```

I want to resize the image after it gets rendered in the page as in i want to change hei=150 and wid=150.

Note: My full image url(including hei,wid) comes from a service so i cant change it there. Any suggestion?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery resizing image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143517/jquery-resizing-image)

Answer (score 0):

If I got your intent correctly than you can use jQuery. Add an `id` attribute to your image so it'll be easy to select. For example `id="myImg"`

Then using jQuery CSS function:

```
  $("#myImg").css({"height" : 123 , "width" : 123});
```

Just change the 123 to the size you want or even put a variable name.