# Resize an image without losing aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have to show photo images of users in a div of 120px by 120px. 
The problem is that images may have different sizes:

- Be smaller
- Greater
- Do not be square. The big problem.

Is there any way to insert images inside the square **without losing the aspect ratio**?

Note: Images are displayed as **background-image**. I prefer CSS, but it could be javascript or jquery.

Very important: need to be **supported by IE8**.

Comment: You might consider using the [**background-size-polyfill**](https://github.com/louisremi/background-size-polyfill) for IE8

Answer (score -2):

try to use jQuery. You can define required height and width of the picture while preserving the aspect ratio.

Check this example.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.story-small img').each(function() {
    var maxWidth = 100; // Max width for the image
    var maxHeight = 100;    // Max height for the image
    var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
    var width = $(this).width();    // Current image width
    var height = $(this).height();  // Current image height

    // Check if the current width is larger than the max
    if(width > maxWidth){
        ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
        $(this).css("width", maxWidth); // Set new width
        $(this).css("height", height * ratio);  // Scale height based on ratio
        height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
    }

    // Check if current height is larger than max
    if(height > maxHeight){
        ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
        $(this).css("height", maxHeight);   // Set new height
        $(this).css("width", width * ratio);    // Scale width based on ratio
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
    }
```

});

Source: http://ericjuden.com/2009/07/jquery-image-resize/

Comment: When you copy complete code, please link the source... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143517/jquery-resizing-image

Comment: This is for background-image?

Comment: Sorry, propably for actual images using the img tag only.

Answer (score -3):

Yes. You can maintain the aspect ratio of background images using the CSS rules:

```
background-size: cover;
background-size: contain;
```

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

Comment: This is not supported by IE8

Comment: Not supported on IE8 :-(